# Fetch photos from Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

Currently I'm able to fetch the photos of the logged in user in my app. But I want to fetch the photos from my instagram developer account in which I have registered my app. Is this possible? Currently,

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed/?access_token=%@",appDelegate.instagram.accessToken];
```

fetches the detail of the logged in user. But I want to get the photos from my client's instagram account. Replacing 'self' in the above url with client's username doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: I think you need to login with your client's account :) !

Comment: You misunderstood. The users of the app should be able to see the photos of the client.

Comment: The client is the person who asked me to build the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use the `/users/user-id/media/recent` Endpoint?

Example from [Instagram API Documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed), to get Feed for UserID = 3, use following

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Returns

```
{
    "data": [{
        "comments": {
            "data": [],
            "count": 0
        },
        "caption": {
            "created_time": "1296710352",
            "text": "Inside le truc #foodtruck",
            "from": {
                "username": "kevin",
                "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
                "type": "user",
                "id": "3"
            },
            "id": "26621408"
        },
        "likes": {
            "count": 15,
            "data": [{
                "username": "mikeyk",
                "full_name": "Mike Krieger",
                "id": "4",
                "profile_picture": "..."
            }, {...subset of likers...}]
        },
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/BWrVZ/",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "created_time": "1296710327",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "type": "image",
        "users_in_photo": [],
        "filter": "Earlybird",
        "tags": ["foodtruck"],
        "id": "22721881",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 37.778720183610183,
            "longitude": -122.3962783813477,
            "id": "520640",
            "street_address": "",
            "name": "Le Truc"
        }
    },
    {
        "videos": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
                "width": 480,
                "height": 480
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640
            },
        "comments": {
            "data": [{
                "created_time": "1279332030",
                "text": "Love the sign here",
                "from": {
                    "username": "mikeyk",
                    "full_name": "Mikey Krieger",
                    "id": "4",
                    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1242695_75sq_1293915800.jpg"
                },
                "id": "8"
            },
            {
                "created_time": "1279341004",
                "text": "Chilako taco",
                "from": {
                    "username": "kevin",
                    "full_name": "Kevin S",
                    "id": "3",
                    "profile_picture": "..."
                },
                "id": "3"
            }],
            "count": 2
        },
        "caption": null,
        "likes": {
            "count": 1,
            "data": [{
                "username": "mikeyk",
                "full_name": "Mikeyk",
                "id": "4",
                "profile_picture": "..."
            }]
        },
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/D/",
        "created_time": "1279340983",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "type": "video",
        "users_in_photo": null,
        "filter": "Vesper",
        "tags": [],
        "id": "363839373298",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "full_name": "Kevin S",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "location": null
    },
   ]
}
```

Comment: But this gets random photos displayed on the user's profile, and not the photos posted by the user himself.

Comment: Ye..It helped. Apparently I had been using username instead of userid. Got it right now.

Comment: Cool. I ran into this situation too when evaluating the Users end points.

Comment: But isn't the access token the access token of the user and not of the client?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram only provides the API to get the feeds of self .. Have a look on

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/userID/media/recent

this i hope it provides some recent medias of a user for more info look at this

http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/